# How to find if there is related data?

Tags: java, database, jpa

Good evening. I'm developing a project using JPA and man kinds of relationship like OneToMany, ManyToMany, etc. There is anyway to find if Table X, for example have related data with table Y ?

I can use Reflection but I don't see it like the best solution since I read that it can impact the application performance.

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "related data", can you give sample of both tables and what do you want to find out?

Comment: Yes I want select data that does not have relationship with any other tables. For example, I have table X... I want select all data of X that does not have foreign keys with data in other tables. Got it ? Sorry my english is very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for database metadata. You can obtain [database metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) from database connection via [getMetaData() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData()).

Example:

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = dbConnection.getMetaData();
```

Look at the [getExportedKeys()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method of the obtained `DatabaseMetaData` implementation.

It retrieves a description of the foreign key columns that reference the given table's primary key columns (the foreign keys exported by a table).

Comment: More than "know" if a table have exported keys, I need to know if there is data filled in other tables with that key. Anyway I will check if I can do it by your solution.

Comment: To verify the data existence by these keys you should make a `SELECT` query with either `INNER` or `OUTER` joins.

Comment: I would like a generic solution because this way you suggested I would have to do a different select/inner to each table and each relationship.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to query the database without making and calling the query. Metadata tells you whether you have relations between tables. But it does not give you the data stored in those tables. To check the presence of data in tables you are interested in you should make and call a query. As an option you can make a stored procedure on the server that operates with the system tables to get metadata and invokes queries to check the data presence. And then call this stored procedure from your java code.

Comment: I got it! Maybe would be easier if I do a stored procedure as you suggested. Thank you very much, I will acept this one.